# Create a formula using importrange and likely index match to return value from another workbook

Tags: arrays, filter, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I need to return value into A3 of workbook1, sheet1 from the corresponding value in G2:G, workbook2, sheet1 where the email address in Workbook 1, sheet1 is in B2 matches the email in workbook2, sheet, C2:C

I was trying vlookup but I don't think that can return what I require due to the position of the cells. It was returning random results from Column G2:G

I also tried:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet!$c$2:c"),MATCH(B3,IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet!$G$2:G"),0))
```

The above does not seem to return the right results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(B3, IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet!C2:G"), 5, 0)
```